# Partial deserialisation of an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a master XML schema that has three classes in

```
<jobs>
<job>
    <id>123-123-123-123</id>
    <aspect1>
        <...></...>
    </aspect1>
    <aspect2>
        <...></...>
    </aspect2>
    <aspect3>
        <...></...>
    </aspect3>
</job>
</jobs>
```

The receiver classes are all set up fine (if all three aspects elements are filled with their respective properties, it's read in without an issue). The issue comes if (say) aspect2 is missing from the object when I get a XmlException thrown.

My XML reader is a simple affair

```
    public static Jobs JobData;

    public static bool ProcessData()
    {
        try
        {
            var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Jobs));
            var r = new StreamReader(jobsapp.Singleton.AppContext.Assets.Open("schemaJobsV101.xml"));
            JobData = (Jobs)s.Deserialize(r);
            r.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.Write("file not found");
            return false;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("invalid operation");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to read the XML file to allow me to have just one element (aspect1, 2 or 3)?

Comment: Can you change the xml schema? In this case it would help to have a list of `<aspect>`

Comment: unfortunately not -it's a fixed schema generated from a SQL result

Comment: Can you give a few more details about when and how the exception is thrown?  Schema validation during reading is [disabled by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8f0h7att%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: If I feed in an XML file that does not contain all three aspects (so just has aspect1 say without having the elements of aspects 2 and 3 present), the exception is thrown. The full schema being used for to deserialise looks like this <masterwork><work><aspect1></aspect1><aspect2></aspect2><aspect3></aspect3></work></masterwork> which then goes to a class system that replicates this